# Blend Bitmap while animation

Tags: java, android, bitmap, blending

I'm developing an Android application and I would like to blend Bitmap with a filter like "Multiply" or "Difference" from Photoshop. Bitmap1 is translating horizontally and Bitmap2 vertically.

I had few ideas :

1) Create a method which do some calculation to find the intersection part of the two Bitmap (Requires to cross 2 matrix every frame, very heavy, seems impossible ?). Then crop the intersection on the 2 Bitmap, blend them, and finally draw it. Another idea would be to do a ANDing  between the two Bitmap, maybe faster than the other method, does thi function already exist ?

2) OpenGL ES ? But I really don't understand how to use it.

3) But recently I have found this sample code which blend two Bitmap on a canvas and use a paint. The result is the one I want BUT there is still no animation. So I've create a new Class (extends View) in addition to this activity, with the method onDraw(Canvas canvas).

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_compo);

       Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bm1);
       Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bm2);
       blend(bm1,bm2);
    }

private void blend(Bitmap bm1, Bitmap bm2){

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int h = metrics.heightPixels;
    int w = metrics.widthPixels;

    /// BLEND MODE ///
    // Create result image
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBitmap(result);

    // Get proper display reference
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), result);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo1);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    // Draw base
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm2, 0, 0, null);

    // Draw overlay
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));
    paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bm1, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP));

    canvas.drawRect(700, 700, bm2.getWidth(), bm2.getHeight(), paint);
}
```

Here is the result with changing the value in 'canvas.drawRect()' :

[Before translation](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=540054Screenshot20140620110642.png)
[After translation](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=573631Screenshot20140620110516.png)

Do you have other solutions ? Or suggestions which would help to realize my filter on animate views ? (The perfect solutions would be to add something like android:blendMode="Multiply" in the XML, but it doesn't seem as easy)

Thank you in advance. J'.